# How to change wordpress pagination urls from sitename.com/pagename/2/ to sitename.com/pagename/?page=2?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm using `Post name` permalink structure on my Wordpress site like following:

`http://sitename.com/sample-post/`

The problem is when i'm trying to access page using "page" argument like:

`http://sitename.com/pagename/?page=2`

it redirects by the following url:

`http://sitename.com/pagename/2/`

Any suggestions how to fix this issue?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You try to use **add_query_arg()**

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_query_arg/